# auto increment in mysql skips some numbers after load command

Tags: mysql, csv

I know auto increment skips if rows are deleted but I am not deleting any rows.here is what I am doing.
My table has a **sno** column which is auto incremented and is also the primary key.Initially the table is empty.Then I load a CSV file as

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'hello5.csv' 
INTO TABLE failure_report.master_entry
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
ignore 2 rows
(@sno,@var1,line,section,station,system,sub_system,equipment,sub_equipment,failure_time,rectified_time,duration,description,rectification,lmd,origin,attended_by,reported_by,@a)
set failure_date =STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%c/%e/%Y');
```

this works fine and I get my sno column auto incremented.But then I again import another csv the auto using the same code as above( just the filename changes) and then **sno** skips some numbers and begins counting from a new number( the counting then goes fine) i.e there is gap of some numbers in between those two csv file data rows.
In every csv file I have to ignore the first two rows.

**UPDATE** The problem seems to be in csv files because the same number of numbers are skipped every time after a particular file but the CSV files seems fine.The following file for example causes the next numbering to be skipped by 26.
http://speedy.sh/vns6Q/hello10.csv

Comment: Are the IDs being loaded from the CSV files themselves?  Are the "skipped" IDs the 2 rows being ignored?

Comment: I am not storing the IDS of the csv and creating my own.No,because there is a difference of more than two in the **sno**

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look.